# Static nested class access throwing NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, nested, noclassdeffounderror, nested-class, unhandled-exception

I'm trying to use a Utility class made up of static nested classes for common functionality.  These static nested classes are implementing a command style interface:

```
public interface BooleanFunction{
    public boolean execute();
}
```

The class holding these common class implementing this interface is:

```
public class ExBooleans {

    public static class isComponentOpen implements BooleanFunction {

        private int widgetId;
        private int componentId;

        public isComponentOpen(int widgetId, int componentId) {
            this.widgetId = widgetId;
            this.componentId = componentId;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean execute() {
            return Widgets.getComponent(this.widgetId, this.componentId) != null;
        }
    }
```

This is meant to be called like so:

```
ExUtilities.makeCondition(new ExBooleans.isComponentOpen(RANGE_WIDGET_ID, RANGE_COOK_COMPONENT_ID), 1000)
```

Where `makeCondition` accepts a `BooleanFunction` :

```
public static boolean makeCondition (final BooleanFunction booleanFunction, int timeout){
    return Utilities.waitFor(new Condition() {
        @Override
        public boolean validate() {
            return booleanFunction.execute();
        }
    }, timeout);
}
```

This is all meant to provide a wrapper around the `Utilities.waitFor(Condition c, int timeout)` function for cleaner more readable code.

However, when I call `makeCondition` passing in the `ExBooleans.isComponentOpen` I receive a runtime error :

```
Unhandled exception in thread ~threadnumber~: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: api/ExBooleans$isComponentOpen
```

at the line containing the call from above:

```
ExUtilities.makeCondition(new ExBooleans.isComponentOpen(RANGE_WIDGET_ID, RANGE_COOK_COMPONENT_ID), 1000)
```

Any help in solving this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: how you are executing this ? using cmd line or IDE?

Comment: looks fine to me, are you sure about the class being present in the classpath

Comment: A closed source client, I can't run from cmd line or IDE.  Scripts are compiled out and run in the client that I have no control over.

Comment: @ArunPJohny the class files are located right alongside all of my other api class files.  I'm not sure how it couldn't be found.

Comment: how is the code exported

Comment: There should be two class files `ExBooleansn.class` and `ExBooleans$isComponentOpen.class` in the shipped code

Comment: @ArunPJohny I am seeing both of those class files along with the rest of my code `ExBooleans.class` `ExBooleans$isComponentOpen.class`.

Comment: how is it shipped, is it a jar file

Comment: @ArunPJohny the closed client I use to run the code is a jar that resides alongside my class files.  I load up the jar and run my class files through that client.

Comment: @ArunPJohny I've narrowed down the problem a tad.  If I pull the `isOpenedComponent` into `ExUtilities` where the `makeCondition` and `interface` reside then it works?  Is it required that these be held in the same parent class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the problem by pull the `interface` and `makeCondition` methods into a separate class that housed both those and the utility implementations `isComponentOpen`, etc.  With these all nested in one class I am no longer getting the error, and the code probably makes more sense grouped together.

I am still unsure where the error was coming from though.